# MissingInteropData exception when initialising UWP share contract

Tags: c#, uwp

I've been unable to personally reproduce this error on any of my development machines, but it's been reported several users. When trying to initalise a share contract to share files, an exception occours.

```
StorageFile ExportFile = await model.Export();

if (ExportFile == null) return;

if (DataTransferManager.IsSupported())
{
    DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView().DataRequested +=
        (sender, e) => Share_DataRequested(sender, e, ExportFile);
    DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
}
else
{
    ErrorHelper.showError("Your device does not support sharing.");
}
```

This code calls the function:

```
private void Share_DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args, StorageFile file)
{
    try
    {
        args.Request.Data.Properties.Title = file.DisplayName;
        args.Request.Data.SetStorageItems(new List<StorageFile>() { file });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        args.Request.FailWithDisplayText("Error occured");
        ErrorHelper.showErrorReporter("Export error", e.Message + Environment.NewLine + e.StackTrace, "The export failed.", BugType.Export_Error);
    }
}
```

This fails for some reason when attempting 'SetStorageItems' with the following stack trace:

```
ComTypeMarshalling_MissingInteropData, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Windows.Storage.IStorageItem>. For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623485
   at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x43bf7e
   at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x43c0ba
   at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x43901c
   at Songbook!<BaseAddress>+0x19f791b
   at Songbook.Models.Exporters.ExportMaster.Share_DataRequested(ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager sender, ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataRequestedEventArgs args, Storage.StorageFile file)
```

I've been unable to a solution to this anywhere, anybody got any suggestions?

Comment: Where is located the file you are trying to share ? Is it something from your application cache or a file that the user can provide ? You may need to have to track the file to not loose the access. I don't know if it will help, but you can have a look at [StorageApplicationPermissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at the ApplicationPermissions, the file is created in the same routine in the [temporary app data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data#temporary-app-data) folder and that is the item being stored

Comment: Same error, have you solved ?

Comment: I'm afraid not, still seems to be occurring in a minority of users

Comment: Turns out it was just a minority of users who were reporting the issue. The issue is actually present in all "Release" builds, however whenever I build the project in "Debug" it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm late to the party, but maybe it still helps... The problem occurs on release builds (using .NET native toolchain compiler), when referencing the `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` NuGet package in version 5.3 or newer. It seems there is some type mismatch / casting problem going on under the hood. Try to explicitly setting the type passed to the `SetStorageItems` method:

```
IEnumerable<IStorageItem> files = new IStorageItem[] {file};
args.Request.Data.SetStorageItems(files);
```

If this still does not help, a quick fix (although not very future-proof) might be to just downgrade the `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` reference to 5.2.4.

Comment: Thank you so much, explicitly declaring the type did the trick!